# Filter list while in for loop in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have this list and I have to display in different divs the `active` from the list and those who are `inactive`.

```
<v-ons-card
  v-for="item in items.data"
  :key="item.id"
> </v-ons-card>
```

Items come for this part of the code.

```
computed: mapState({
    items: state => state.items.items
  })
```

`state.items` looks like this

```
const state = {
  items: {
    data: [],
  },
};
```

I'm thinking if I can do this,

```
v-for="item in items.data.active"
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Can you share how your `state.items` looks like ?

Comment: updated the content. It looks like that.

Comment: How do you determine if data is active or inactive ?

Comment: You may try use `v-if="true === item.active"` in the list of active divs and `v-if="false === item.active"` in the list of inactive. But best solution is to create `getters` in your store to let them filter the write items instead of messing up your view part of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
computed: {
    activeItems() {
      return this.items.data.filter((x) => x.active);
    },
    inactiveItems() {
      return this.items.data.filter((x) => !x.active);
    },
  },
```

```html
<div>Active items:</div>
<v-ons-card
  v-for="item in activeItems"
  :key="item.id"
></v-ons-card>

<div>Inactive items:</div>
<v-ons-card
  v-for="item in inactiveItems"
  :key="item.id"
></v-ons-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getters in Vuex or computed property.